# DAX formula to get total number of sales in a Calculated Column at a lookup table

Tags: filter, datatable, count, powerbi, dax

I have received answers to my last question. Thanks to all. Now I have another query. I have a lookup table, called Products and a transaction table, called Sales. The relationship between them is one to many. I want to make a Calculated Column at Product to get the total number of sales for each product. I tried to apply Calculate function as solution.
Product [total number of sales] =
Countrows ( Filter (Product, Calculate (Sum( Sales [SalesAmount])))).

I expected products in each row in Product table shall filter the sum of sales amount and generate a virtual table with all the entries related to a particular product. And finally, Countrows shall count the number of entries. But on the contrary, it resulted with same number in each row.
I am just a beginner in DAX. I tried to solve it depending on context transition concept. But my guess was wrong. Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RELATEDTABLE`:

If you just want the number of entries in the Sales table per product:

```
=
COUNTROWS(
    RELATEDTABLE( Sales )
)
```

If you want the total sales per product:

```
=
SUMX(
    RELATEDTABLE( Sales ),
    Sales[SalesAmount]
)
```

Comment: Yes...Thank you so much. I was confused with so many new functions. You have cast my confusion away. Thanks.